# Zurb Foundation Semantic Grid Trouble

Tags: grid, semantic-markup, zurb-foundation

Zurb Foundation is great, and everything but semantic grid works just fine.
I have zurb-foundation gem installed ( the latest public release ); 
Copy-paste markup example and Scss Example of semantical grid from Zurb official site to index.html and app.scss and it works incorrectly: page is not responsive on "medium landscape" and lower formats, and when I resize my page - scrollbar is appears.
I found the same question on https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/foundation-framework-/Yjh_9f21foQ and this page - http://szabinho.com/zurb/ is a good illustration what i'm talking about.
Can everyone show me the practical example of semantical grid by Zurb. It is very powerful and cool framework, and one thing stopped me from using - this annoying trouble.
Hope you help me. Thanks!

Comment: You might find http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ a nice alternative to try out, if you want a handy frontend framework. It has more features.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but it important for me to use framework with sass and semantical grid maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, when using Sass and the mixins to compile my semantic grid.

I noticed that .row had a minimum width set to it:

```
.row {
  width: 960px;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 768px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

So this would mean that all rows would be at least 768px wide. You can override this setting in app.css (or scss is you are using SASS) like this:

```
.row {
  min-width: 0!important;
}
```

I also noticed that this problem only occured when using SASS mixins like `@include outerRow()` and `innerRow()` when I went back to using `<div class="row"><div class="twelve columns">` I didn't get this error.